# Show that a function is bounded using Taylor expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, holomorphic-functions

Let $f\in \mathcal{O}(D)$ (where $D=\mathbb{D}(0,1)), f(0)=0, f'(0)=1, |f'(z)|\le 2$ for $z\in D$.

let $g(z)=\frac{f'(z)-1}{z}$ for $z\in D\setminus\{0\}$.

I try to show that $|g(z)| \le 3$.

What I did:

The Taylor expansion gives:

$f(z)=f(0)+f'(0)z+f''(0)\frac{z^2}{2} + \sum_{n=3}^{+\infty} a_nz^n $

$f$ is holomorphic so deriving the series gives:

$f'(z)=f'(0)+f''(0)z + \sum_{n=3}^{+\infty} na_nz^{n-1} $

So $||g(z)|| = ||f''(0) + \sum_{n=3}^{+\infty} na_nz^{n-2}|| \le ||f''(0) ||+ ||\sum_{n=3}^{+\infty} na_nz^{n-2}||$

By the Cauchy inequality for the holomorphic $f'$:

$f''(0) = (f')'(0) \le \sup_{|w|= z}|f'(w)| \le 2$.

But  I didn't manage to show that $||\sum_{n=3}^{+\infty} na_nz^{n-2}||\le 1$

Could we use the Taylor Young formulae and the fact that $||\sum_{n=3}^{+\infty} na_nz^{n-1} = \circ(z^2)||$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have to use Taylor expansion? This looks like an easy application of the Schwarz Lemma to $f'(z) - 1$.

Answer (score 2):

For $|z|=1$ you get $$|g(z)|=|f'(z)-1|\le |f'(z)|+1\le 3$$ and thus by the maximum principle $|g(z)|\le 3$ for all $z\in D$. $g$ is holomorphic as the (formal) singularity in its definition at $z=0$ is removable.

Comment: $g$ is only defined for $|z| < 1$ but not for $|z|=1$.

Comment: Then it is still true on $\bar{\Bbb D}(0,1-\epsilon)$ with bound $3/(1-ϵ)$ for any $\epsilon>0$ and thus under intersection of all these cases on $D$ with bound $3$.